# Using lapply function on svychisq

Tags: r, syntax, lapply

I have a dataset named "drugs" and I created a weighted dataset named "weighted_data".

```
weighted_data <- svydesign(id = ~cluster, 
                           strata = ~strata, 
                           weights = ~weights, 
                           data = drugs, 
                           nest = TRUE)
```

I can use this function to perform a chi-squared test on all the variables to see if the proportions in states with medical marijuana laws are significantly different from states without medical marijuana laws.

```
svychisq(~religion_importance + medmj_law, design=weighted_data)
```

Naturally, I don't want to do this for all 12 variables, so I want to use an lapply function.

```
lapply(names(drugs[-c(1, 14:16)]), function(x)
  svychisq(
    as.formula(bquote(~.(as.name(x))) + medmj_law ), 
    design = weighted_data))
```

But I keep getting *"Error in as.formula(bquote(~.(as.name(x))) + medmj_law) : object 'medmj_law' not found"*. Something must be wrong with my syntax.

For reference, the first variable is "medmj_law" and variables 2-13 are the 12 categorical variables I want to do chi-squared tests on. And I used this code to calculate proportions, which works.

```
overall_table_weighted <- lapply(names(drugs[,-c(14:16)]), function(x)
  svytable(bquote(~.(as.name(x))), design=weighted_data))

overall_prop_weighted <- lapply(names(drugs[,-c(14:16)]), function(x)
  round(prop.table(svytable(bquote(~.(as.name(x))), design=weighted_data))*100, 2))
```

Comment: Though there are other methods (I guess), `as.formula()` works well with a string as its first argument. In your case, `as.formula` does not try to add the string "medmj_law" to the formula but instead looks for an object with this name. But you don't have that object in the environment of the anonymous function that you pass to `lapply`.    
Try this: `as.formula(paste("~", x, " + medmj_law"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from [@benimwolfspelz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13708008/benimwolfspelz)'s comment:

> Though there are other methods (I guess), `as.formula()` works well with a string as its first argument. In your case, `as.formula` does not try to add the string `"medmj_law"` to the formula but instead looks for an object with this name. But you don't have that object in the environment of the anonymous function that you pass to `lapply`. Try this: `as.formula(paste("~", x, " + medmj_law"))`

Full code:

```
#Chi-Squared Tests
chisq_weighted <- lapply(names(drugs[-c(1, 14:16)]), function(x)
  svychisq(as.formula(paste("~", x, " + medmj_law")), design = weighted_data))
pvalues_weighted <- lapply(names(drugs[-c(1, 14:16)]), function(x)
  svychisq(as.formula(paste("~", x, " + medmj_law")), design = weighted_data)$p.value)
```

Thank you [@benimwolfspelz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13708008/benimwolfspelz)!!

Answer (score -1):

This is easy just do the following:

```
lapply(names(drugs[-c(1, 14:16)]), function(x)
  svychisq(
    bquote(~.(as.name(x))+ medmj_law), 
    design = weighted_data))
```

You're welcome.

Comment: That doesn't work, now I get "Error in x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop("no terms component nor attribute") : no terms component nor attribute"